Do we use "like crazy" for positive or neutral activities and "like hell" for negative ones?
The Dictionary just say "

run/hurt/fight etc like hell (informal not polite): to run, fight etc
very quickly or very much

"

like crazy/mad: ​(informal) very fast, hard, much, etc.
We worked like crazy to get it done on time.

But the dictionary doesn't say how they are used.
I guess we use "like crazy" for positive or neutral activities and "like hell" for negative ones.
"He was so excited that he danced like crazy" (positive)
I guess people don't say "He was so excited that he danced like hell"
"I ran like hell when I saw the tiger" (negative)
I don't think people say "I ran like crazy when I saw the tiger"

I'd run like crazy if I saw a tiger; I'd shout for help like crazy if my boat was sinking; I'd work like hell if I was promised a £1000 bonus. You are mistaken about 'like crazy' being for positive situations and 'like hell' being for negative ones.

'Like crazy' and 'like hell' are just casual/slang/informal expressions for 'a lot'.

No, either one can be used for either positive or negative situations.
"When I saw the tiger, I ran like crazy." "When I saw the tiger, I ran like hell."
"The thief fought like crazy when the police tried to arrest him." "The thief fought like hell when the police tried to arrest him."
"She kissed her boyfriend like crazy when he proposed." "She kissed her boyfriend like hell when he proposed."
All of those work.
The difference is that "like crazy" is polite and "like hell" is somewhat crude. I'd classify it as "mildly crude". Not in the same category as the F-word but not something you'd say to your pastor.

Crazy and hell are both informal, but hell, damn, etc, have not been generally seen as  'cuss words' in Britain for about 50 years at least.

@MichaelHarvey Ok. In the US, these would be considered mild curses. https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/is-hell-a-curse-word/ and many other sources.

My father used to shout 'HELL' or 'DAMN' in a very loud voice (around 1960) if he did something like bang his thumb with a hammer while doing carpentry. My mother said that I and my sister were not to copy that.

I'm guessing this local newspaper headline would not happen in the USA: 'Portsmouth family tell of leaky toilet hell'?

@MichaelHarvey It could happen. Newspapers here will print mild vulgarities. I'd say relatively unlikely, but I wouldn't be shocked if they did.

The "kissed ... like hell" example strikes me as very odd.

Jay, not sure about she kissed her boyfriend like hell...Otherwise, I agree.

@TimR (shrug) Okay, the important point isn't that particular example. I was just making up examples off the top of my head. Perhaps better would be, "When the police showed up, Bob ran like hell" (negative) "When the 100-meter dash began, Bob ran like hell" (positive)

I think you could add a "kissing...like there was no tomorrow" to the "like there was no tomorrow" question. :-)
